# Batch Processing of Newsletter thru plesk (PHPList)

Tags: php, email, plesk, phplist

I need to send newsletters say to 20,000 email IDs, but in batches and I am very new to this mail sending process so I got stuck at the beginning only.

I have my mail server is a shared server, so I have the limit say 100 emails per hour, but I need to send this to entire 20,000 email IDs on database. 
I have following things on my site

1. List of receivers (in a table called emails)
2. Email Setting form (with fields like IP, email, password, batch size, interval)
3. table for above fields..
4. My site is hosted on Plesk (Windows-based Web Server).

I had googled for this and I got phpList perfectly matching with all my requirements but 
I need my own interface also it can be installed in CPanel I done know how to install it on Plesk.

Please someone help me on this.

Comment: I didn't understand what is your question. Do you did assistance in installing PHPList on Plesk in order to have it via Web?

Comment: Make sure that whatever you're doing is not spam... in a lot of countries it's illegal.

Comment: I need all those listed above should be working in my php mailer... and I found PHPList matching to what I need.. so I tried installing but problem was PHPList works with Apache but my server in windows with IIS.. hope u understand @pankar

Comment: To my knowledge, your hosting provider should give you out of the box the ability to install PHPList via your Plesk Control Panel. If this is not the case then you should contact them for further details. If you run by yourself the Web Server you can consult this [link](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/phplist-on-iis) for instructions on how to install PHPList on IIS

Answer (score 0):

First you need to setup the mail server setting through plesk's "mail" setting.

Once you done with the above configuration, go to the www/public_html folder
1) upload you phplist file there.
2) do the necessary settings in config.php
3) install it thorough (you may also get the installation instructions here : http://docs.phplist.com/PhplistInstallation.html)

Note : Email sending limits only depends on your sever configuration + your ISP can spam laws.